# How to merge tables with disparate schemas into a superset table?

Tags: sql, merge, mariadb, database-schema

I'm not sure if "superset" is the most accurate way to describe what I'm trying to do here, but I have two tables like so:

Table A:

`a | b | c | f | h | j | o | q`

Table B:

`c | a | d | f | g | h | i | j | p | q`

What I would like to do is merge them into a table that contains all records from both tables, with each row having data in its original column, including all *distinct* columns from *both* tables, like this:

Merged table:

`a | b | c | d | f | g | h | i | j | o | p | q`

I'm not fussy about the order in particular, since I'm trying to merge staging tables together. They `c` and the `a` columns could be flopped in the final table - it doesn't matter much to me.

This means that some columns won't contain any data for half of the table but that is the idea - **I don't want to lose any information**, and not all the tables have a compatible schema. If two column names are identical, they are the same logical column though and there should not be two of them in the new table (I will manually ensure logically identical columns are named the same).

I've been using something like `INSERT INTO new SELECT * FROM old1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM old2` but that doesn't work here since, forgetting about `UNION`, that only works if the schemas match. In this case, the new table will have a schema that combines the old schemas. The `MERGE` command seems to have similar issues, expecting somewhat compatible schemas.

Is there any way to do this automatically? Each of the tables has close to 70 columns, the order doesn't line up, and I have to do a dozen of these merges, so I'm trying to automate the refactor somehow with SQL.

Using `NATURAL JOIN` was suggested, but this does not seem like it would work - for example, Table A:

`a | b | c`

`1 | 5 | 35`

Table B:

`b | d  | f`

`5 | 66 | 34`

`NATURAL JOIN` yields:

`a | b | c | d | f`

`1 | 5 | 35| 66| 34`

What I want is not a natural join, just pure concatenation with no duplicate columns:

`a | b | c | d | f`

`1 | 5 | 35|   |`

`| 5 |   | 66|34`

Comment: Do your tables have rows & columns? This looks more like text strings to me.

Comment: @wildplasser Yeah, they do (and a lot - hundreds of thousands, or millions, of rows) - the data is immaterial; I just listed the columns for simplicity

Comment: Please add some ddl to you question, instead of the text gibberish. (there is a database-schema tag ...)

Comment: @wildplasser I literally don't have a meaningful schema at this point. It's 70 columns of VARCHAR(255). Not all columns are defined for all rows/all tables. That's basically it

Comment: Maybe you could transform your millions of rows to a meaningful schema?

Comment: @wildplasser That has to wait until the end, when I've already merged all the tables together.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no easy way to do this. Build UNION queries or a custom UDF. In Access I would use VBA to either build query objects or write data to table. Even with VBA, would need a 'mapping' table that defines field pairs. So if MariaDB has similar functionality, apply same concept.

Consider this for a UNION:

```
SELECT "A" AS Src, a, b, c, Null AS d, f, Null AS g, h, Null AS i, j, o, Null AS p, q FROM TableA
UNION 
SELECT "B", a, Null, c, d, f, g, h, i, j, Null, p, q FROM TableB;
```

Comment: I am using MariaDB, not Access. Also, it is simply not practical to explicitly name all the columns. Is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: As I said, I don't know any other way. I understand 70 columns is a lot to type but once and done x 12. I know you are using MariaDB. I only mentioned Access VBA as a for instance. I can only assume MariaDB has programming capability. Or do you need to use VB.net or PHP or some other app as GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the tables are different columns count, they can still be UNION-ed like so:

```
SELECT a, b, c, NULL AS d, f, NULL AS g, h, NULL AS i, j, o, NULL AS p, q
FROM tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT a, NULL AS b, c, d, f, g, h, i, j, NULL AS o, p, q
FROM tbl2;
```

Sadly  in MySQL/MariaDB you can't do it without typing all column names explicitly and positioning them manually.

SAS PROC SQL has support for what you need with it's OUTER UNION CORR operator. There the solution will be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
OUTER UNION CORR
SELECT * FROM tbl2;
```

Unfortunately it's not (yet) available in MySQL/MariaDB. You may eventually emulate something like it using tricky use of GROUP_CONCAT and CONCAT, IFNULL and other functions by playing with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS in order to generate SELECT query as prepared statement... but I would personally not go in that direction.

Anyway - as a basic **starting point** of this **BAD idea**... The following query will list all unique columns from both tables (if the database is 'test' and the tables are 'tbl1' and 'tbl2'):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tbl1'
UNION
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tbl2'
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME;
```

Now we will concat them in one field separated by commas:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("NULL AS ", COLUMN_NAME)) AS columns
FROM (  SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tbl1'
        UNION
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tbl2'
        ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
) AS grouped_columns;
```

then we can run this "command" via prepared SELECT statement which in this example will print a starting row with NULL values:

```
SET @s:='';
SELECT @s:=CONCAT('SELECT ', columns) AS start_row
            FROM
            (
                SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('NULL AS ',COLUMN_NAME)) AS columns
                FROM (  SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tbl1'
                        UNION
                        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tbl2'
                        ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
                ) AS grouped_columns
            ) AS grouped_columns;
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

This "monster" query will produce something like a hook row...

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    | d    | f    | g    | h    | i    | j    | o    | p    | q    |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

under which you must somehow figure out how to add the entries from tbl1 and tbl2 on the respective positions. So... good luck. I will not struggle to do it :) It is highly inefficient already and I am not even close to the solution. This is a no-go direction for doing what you want. Just type the column names manually.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you seem to want `full join` and `using`:

```
select *
from a full join
     b
     using (a, c, f, j, h, i, j, p, q)
```

MariaDB doesn't support that, but you can do:

```
select *
from a left join
     b
     using (a, c, f, j, h, i, j, p, q)
union all
select *
from a right join
     b
     using (a, c, f, j, h, i, j, p, q)
where a.a is null;
```

Comment: For the USING, is it possibly at all to list all the columns of the appropriate table without explicitly enumerating them? Ideally, I would like to script this on multiple tables without having to plug in all the column names. Thanks!

Comment: @InterLinked . . . You *could* use `natural join` but I think it is an abomination.  It does do exactly what you want, though.

Comment: Hmm... it seems `NATURAL JOIN` combines rows, not columns: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/natural-join.php - the example here is not quite what I'm looking for. I don't want any data combined at all like in this example, where if values in the column matched, the columns are tacked on. I've edited my question to include an example